# A percentage of users which are with rank lower than yours

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

I think I haven't seen such feature, but probably is not bad to have: Basically if you earn some amount of points i.e. 1000 the system could tell you:

you have better ranking than 60% of the users in the system.

Comment: http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/229/test-what-is-my-reputations-percentile

Comment: @YiJiang Doesn't seem to work when I use 1000 for some reason, although I don't see anything wrong with the code. Why not put it in an answer?

Comment: @TheLQ: Works fine for me. Note that the first parameter of the query is the *minimum reputation* of users to include.

Comment: @Yi Jiang - I didn't know that, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, note that there is a non-automated way to find your rank at any given time, not just when you cross interesting thresholds.

1. Click over to the [Users page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users)
2. Find yourself in the list
3. Look at the bottom right corner of the page and take note of which page you're on (the differently colored number)
4. Look at the bottom right corner of the page and see how many total pages of users there are (the rightmost number, by "next")
5. Divide the number from step 3 by the number from step 4

For an even more precise calculation, note that there are seven rows and five columns, for 35 users per page. It's not that much more work to figure out your exact position.

Of course, by the time you've done all that math, your position will probably have changed.

Comment: I know how to make this by hand, but I thought that it's not so difficult to see this number in the User's profile (even cached on a daily basis). After all there is no distinction between user which answers many questions in C# and user with answers in jQuery, right? The position in the list is based on the points earned :)